# SAS 9.3 Procedure Pareto Not found

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS (using SAS 9.3) and trying to use the pareto procedure. When I run my script the log says the procedure cannot be found, however when I run the following I see that SAS\QC is not expired.
From the Log: ERROR: Procedure PARETO not found.

```
proc setinit;
run;
```

Here is the statement I started that uses the Pareto procedure

```
data myset;
input A;
datalines;
1
2
3
4
5
6
;
PROC pareto data=myset;
BY A;
VBAR A = Blue;
run;
```

I've searched around online but haven't found anything helpful. According to the [documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/qcug/63922/HTML/default/viewer.htm#pareto_toc.htm) for SAS 9.2, Pareto is part of the QC module.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and perhaps even a dumb of the relevant part of the log. Your problem is not really replicable as is. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Will do - wasn't sure if that would be relevant since it's claiming the procedure can't be found.

Comment: I added a different example. I can use UNIVARIATE and run a histogram against 'mydataset' but not Pareto...

Comment: Run `PROC PRODUCT_STATUS;RUN;` to see if the QC product was actually installed (versus just licensed).

Comment: Looks like that's the problem - thanks Tom! If you want to answer the question I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use proc `PRODUCT_STATUS` to test if the QC module is actually installed on your system.

There is a nice writeup on this at SAS.  http://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2012/11/12/how-to-find-your-sas-version-and-components-list/